# C++ iterate container backwards N steps

Tags: c++, list, reverse-iterator

In C++ I can use `reverse_iterator` to loop elements of container, say, `list`, backwards.

How do I iterate over a certain number of elements? Not reaching the beginning? This code works, but I feel there is a better way.

```
std::list<int> mylist{1,2,3,4,5};
int cnt = 3;
for (auto rit = mylist.rbegin(); rit != mylist.rend(); ++rit) {
    if (cnt == 0) break;
    std::cout << *rit << " ";
    --cnt;
}
```

Expected output `{5, 4, 3}`.

Comment: At least, your solution is robust. It doesn't even fail if there are less than 3 elements in container. This wouldn't be the case if your would use `mylist.rbegin() + 3` as end condition...

Comment: I can add range checks

Comment: The solution you already have also work with all iterator types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the loop as follows:

```
for (auto rit = mylist.rbegin(); rit != std::next(mylist.rbegin(), 3); ++rit)
{
   std::cout << *rit << " ";
}
```

but note that for this to work reliably, you need to check that the list is at least of size 3 or adjust the parameter to `std::next` as in `const auto n = std::min<std::size_t>(3, mylist.size());`.

With C++20, you should be able to go with (obviously not tested)

```
#include <ranges>

for (int n : mylist | std::ranges::reverse_view | std::ranges::take_view(3))
  std::cout << n << "\n";
```

This renders the size testing superfluous, as `take_view` is bound by the range size (it performs this check internally).

Answer (score 4):

> Not reaching the beginning?

If you can guarantee that, then

```
std::copy_n(mylist.rbegin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Or to be safer

```
std::copy_n(mylist.rbegin(), std::min(mylist.size(), std::list<int>::size_type(3)), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YgPFYKYayiS915no)

Answer (score 2):

I would not put incrementing/decrementing and checking the condition in the loop body, but rather put it where you most expect it:

```
std::list<int> mylist{1,2,3,4,5};
int cnt = 3;
for (auto rit = mylist.rbegin(); rit != mylist.rend() && cnt > 0; ++rit,--cnt) {
    std::cout << *rit << " ";
}
```

Now you could for example add a `continue` anywhere in the loop body without making the loop go havoc.

PS: actually I like the other answers better, but I'll leave this one as it is minimal changes and imho incrementing / checking a loop counter inside the loop body is something to be avoided if possible (and it is possible here).